# DirectiveProcessor failed with errors on files in PaxHeader directory on Windows

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, angular-dart, dart-pub

I have an application that is part Polymer Dart and part AngularDart 2, and I'm getting a large string of errors when I attempt to do a `pub get`.  The errors I'm getting look like this:

`[DirectiveProcessor]:
  Failed with 27 errors
Error 1: line 1, column 1 of lib\common\PaxHeader\service.dart and parts: Expected a method, getter, setter or operator declaration
17 gid=234561557
^^`

My Angular dependency is set in my pubspec.yaml as `angular2: "2.0.0-beta.22"` and I am running Dart 1.19.0 on Windows 7 64 bit.  I found this issue on Github:

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5599

This seems to be the exact same problem, but was marked as fixed in alpha48 last December, so I'm not exactly sure what could be happening here.  I have verified with other teams that this issue is not present on OSX.

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: This problem came up again recently (in a bit a different flavour) but should have been fixed again. Can you try a more recent dev-channel version (don't know about availability in Windows)?

Answer (score 1):

Issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7395 goes into greater detail on what the root cause is - the build process for the bundled archive sometimes includes things that Windows tar handlers don't know how to handle, and the devs at Google don't notice because they're working in Unix. It was supposedly fixed permanently in that issue, but that was before the Dart version branched off to be independent and maybe they didn't copy that bit of setup.

I suggest reporting a new issue at https://github.com/dart-lang/angular2/issues and linking to the old 7395.